# How to calculate the sum of week hours?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How can I calculate the sum of week hours?

I have a Campus document like this,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce3beecf32c6e5ba2d767e8"),
    "managers" : [ 
        ObjectId("5cd2a3de1e2d5928b04321b9"), 
        ObjectId("5cd2a34e1e2d5928b04321b7")
    ],
    "admins" : [ 
        ObjectId("5cd3b1d0877c5b07921932dd")
    ],
    "status" : true,
    "name" : "Halliday Hall",
    "address1" : "Oliver Rd",
    "address2" : "Thunder Bay",
    "city" : "Ontario",
    "state" : "Ontario",
    "postCode" : "8465",
    "email" : "halliday@gmail.com",
    "phone" : 8475963269.0,
    "workingDays" : {
        "Sunday" : [ 
            "Closed", 
            "Closed"
        ],
        "Monday" : [ 
            "10:30 AM", 
            "04:30 PM"
        ],
        "Tuesday" : [ 
            "10:00 AM", 
            "05:00 PM"
        ],
        "Wednesday" : [ 
            "Closed", 
            "Closed"
        ],
        "Thursday" : [ 
            "Closed", 
            "Closed"
        ],
        "Friday" : [ 
            "Closed", 
            "Closed"
        ],
        "Saturday" : [ 
            "Closed", 
            "Closed"
        ]
    }
}
```

wokingDays is of type Map

```
workingDays: {
            type: Map,
            of: Array
        }
```

All I want to do is calculate the sum of workings hours

I tried using moment but was getting stuck with the query.

The expected sum in this case would be 13 hrs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  have taken the start time and the end time, and used moment to subtract the time, and then converted the same into hours, we can use this logic inside the iterator and find the difference.

```
const startTime=moment("10:30 AM", "HH:mm a"),
    endTime=moment("04:30 PM", "HH:mm a"),
    duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime)),
    hours = parseInt(duration.asHours());
console.log(`No of hours = ${hours}`);
```

Please find the below code where i am iterating and finding out the no of hours in a week,

```
const moment = require('moment');
const req_object = {
    "_id" : "5ce3beecf32c6e5ba2d767e8",
    "workingDays" : {
        "Sunday" : [ 
            "Closed", 
            "Closed"
        ],
        "Monday" : [ 
            "10:30 AM", 
            "04:30 PM"
        ],
        "Tuesday" : [ 
            "10:00 AM", 
            "05:00 PM"
        ],
        "Wednesday" : [ 
            "Closed", 
            "Closed"
        ],
        "Thursday" : [ 
            "Closed", 
            "Closed"
        ],
        "Friday" : [ 
            "Closed", 
            "Closed"
        ],
        "Saturday" : [ 
            "Closed", 
            "Closed"
        ]
    }
}

let wd = req_object.workingDays;
let hours = 0;
for (var item in wd) {
    if (wd[item][0] != "Closed") {

        const startTime=moment(wd[item][0], "HH:mm a"),
            endTime=moment(wd[item][1], "HH:mm a"),
            duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
            hours += parseInt(duration.asHours());
    }  
}

console.log(`No of hours = ${hours}`);
```

Please respond, did it work for you.